# how to get nginx 1.9.5 above in amazon ami

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

How can we install and use `nginx 1.9.5` above to use `HTTP/2` in `Amazon AMI`.

Have tried the latest stable version of `nginx 1.10` but once you reload and use

```
nginx -V
```

it still show `1.8`.